# Extra zeroes in field with data type FLOAT

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, mysql-workbench

Okay so I've used phpmyadmin for a while and it I used `FLOAT(7,2)` to format any number to `x.xx`, but when I do this in workbench it always comes out as `xxxxxx.xx` - which is not what I want - I want it formatted to be any number with two decimals.

Settings: https://i.gyazo.com/8a7935a9980f456dffdfb05d9663cde0.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uncheck `Zero Fill` checkbox and try again.

**without zero fill**
[image: without zero fill]

**with zero fill**
[image: with zero fill]